# WWW::Firefox::Mechanize Local Address

Tags: perl, firefox, ip, mechanize

I use WWW::Mechanize in Perl and it allows me to use a specific IP address by using $mech->local_address($address). Now, I'm using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox. $mech->local_address($address) seems not working. I originally thought WWW::Mechanize::Firefox is an extension of WWW::Mechanize. But it seems not the case. Because Perl complains that it cannot find the method of local_address(). Does any one know any alternative method that allows me to set a specific IP address in WWW::Mechanize::Firefox?

Comment: WWW::Mechanize is a subclass of LWP::UserAgent, to which the method local_address belongs. WWW::Mechanize::Firefox has no relation to LWP::UserAgent, thus no such method. To quote the docs *"WWW::Mechanize::Firefox - use Firefox as if it were WWW::Mechanize"*, which seems to mean no relation to WWW::Mechanize except for a similar interface.

Comment: @Qtax Do you know any alternative WWW::Mechanize::Firefox methods that allow me to change my IP?

Comment: @CMALeung do you have multiple local IP addresses? Why exactly do you need to "change" your IP address?